# IE bind mousemove to body

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, events, bind, mousemove

I am trying to bind a mousemove event to the body. My attempts so far:

```
$('html, body').mousemove(function(event){...});

$('html, body')[0].onmousemove= function(event){...};

$('body').bind('mousemove', function(event){...});

document.onmousemove = function(event){...};

document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].onmousemove = function(event){...};
```

EDIT:

```
window.onmousemove = function(event){...}; // doesn't work either
```

EDIT2: I need the whole body to be responsive, and not only nested elements.

All of these worked, but none did in IE.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Have you already tried: `window.onmousemove = ...`?

Comment: The version of IE is 9. And I am currently trying it with `window.onmousemove` (not the local computer, takes some time)

Comment: If you bind it on the body (for whatever reason) does that body actually have a size? I'm taking a wield guess here, but could it be that your body consists of only very small height, and you're maybe expecting the visible window to be the body?

Comment: Sime Vidas: no, it doesn't (?! – strange…)
Yoshi: Well yes, I do mean the visible area of the body, but the body has sufficient dimensions, because there are quite a few elements within.

Comment: @Sime Vidas, once again: sorry, now I see what it does. However, I need the whole body to be listening, and not only that text element within.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't want it in the body because body is not necessarily the full page.

```
$( document ).mousemove( function () {

});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uDfPj/

Alternatively without jQuery:

```
document.documentElement.onmousemove = function(){};
```

Comment: That worked, but I've done something wrong before: I forgot the `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt whether the onMouseMove event is associated with the body tag.  Can you try it on the window tag?  I haven't tried that though.

Answer (score 0):

try it with the document instead. here's a great sample page that shows it working

http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/tests/mousemove.html

and a compatibility table:
http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/mousemove.html